# InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137 on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I am currently migrating a Laravel site from a virtual hosting to a shared hosting (000webhost). The original admin have left and cannot be reached.

After I copied over the php files and imported the MySQL to new hosting, I updated \public_html\bootstrap\cache\config.php for the paths and MySQL db config. Also I have chmod 755 he permission of `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories.

However when I try to load the site it returns 2 errors:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View
> [auth.login] not found.
>
> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
> file_put_contents(/public_html/storage/framework/sessions/xxxxxxxxxx):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

For the first error, I double checked \public_html\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php is existing. What else should I check?

In some old thread it is suggested to run artisan commands to fix it:

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan
  config:cache

However I cannot run command on shared hosting. Also I do not find /route/ folder and web.php so I cannot do it on web browser too. Can I simply delete all files under /sessions/ & /cache/ and reset my cache manually?

Comment: delete `config.php` file under `bootstrap/cache` then check.

Comment: @DilipHirapara after remove config.php I can see the login screen now! However my SQL connection information are saved in config.php how should I added them back? When I login it return `PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user`

Comment: Later I updated connectionstring in `config/database.php` to get around SQL error. Then ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:
include(/storage/ssd5/593/12921593/public_html/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory